# GPIO switch relay 12V AC

Tags: gpio, relay

Here is my problem

I've built my own home automation by using some relays, driven by 12V AC (read Alternating Current) to switch them.

Now i want to use my raspberry's GPIO pins to switch these relays.

-The GPIO pins deliver 3.3V DC

-My relays need 12V AC to switch

As far as i know i can't use a transistor because it only works for DC?

Is there any solution to this? And i prefer not using any other power source but my raspberry and the 12VAC i already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as i know i can't use a transistor because it only works for
>   DC?

You are correct on not directly using single transistor to drive an AC relay.

You will likely need to use a TRIAC, or additional smaller relay to drive your 12 VAC relays.
You can find lots of help over in "Electrical Stack Exchange" regarding smaller relays and triacs, such as this [Triac Driver Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/37750/questions-regarding-triac-driver-circuit)

The linked page describes using 120 VAC, however, if you follow the comments and answers the circuit will work for your 12 VAC.
[image]

Comment: I've done some research about TRIACS and what do you think about this?
TRIAC i found: 
I max = 0.8A (this should be enaugh for switching a relay)
IGT (Q1) 3 to 25 mA

GPIO delivers 3.3V and the TRIAC gate wants between 3 and 25mA (if i am correct?)

So the resistor for the gate: 3.3/0.025=132ohm
So i will user a resistor of 220ohm maybe?

Comment: Use 3.3 volts for calculating resistor R1 (assume 12mA for LED). 3.3v-1.2v/.012 = 175 ohms.  For other side of the optocoupler, use 12 VAC for all calculations.

Comment: Why the 3.3v-1.2v?

Comment: The Led has a typical voltage drop of 1.2v at 12mA. Remaining voltage is across the resistor

Comment: @PiBuster . I did some further research. I am astounded that I could NOT find an add on board for RPi that has relay contacts output for high level AC switching. I use the "Gertboard" for many applications, but it only uses transistor buffers for switching of DC relays. The Triac circuit I suggested does require the user to build quite a bit of extra circuitry. Perhaps others know of a commercially available (multiple relay) board.

Comment: Why isn't this circuit possible without the Optocoupler?

Comment: @PiBuster The Pi outputs can only tolerate 16 mA output current. I suggested 12mA (LED current) design for opto LED so that current wouldn't be a problem (safety margin). Additionally the opto-coupler protects the Pi from being directly connected (vulnerable) to the 12 VAC circuit.

Comment: Thx for all info Marla!